# GBQ Transpose Dynamically without Execute Immediate

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, transpose

Hi All trying to figure out a way to transpose data in columns dynamically. In the data the distinct number of Traits will increase/decrease.

I know I can hardcode the columns like this

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Produce)
  PIVOT(MAX(Trait_Name) FOR Trait IN ('Color', 'Texture', 'Size'))
```

I can also do it dynamically with Execute Immediate like this

```
execute immediate (
select '''select * from (select * from `wf-gcp-us-ae-merch-prod.eb_analytics_junk.pr_junk_sku_test`)
  pivot(MAX(Trait_Name) for Trait in ("''' ||  string_agg(Trait, '", "')  || '''"))
'''
);
```

The issue with Execute Immediate is the results of that must be stored in a table before it can be used again.  Is there another method to pivot this data dynamically where it can be put in CTE or SubQuery so the script can continue running?

**Source Data**

[image: Base Data]

**Result Data**

[image: Result Data]

Comment: "... before it can be used again ..." - I think this is a key statement in your case. What/how exactly you envision to use result again? knowing/clearing this might totally change the view on  the issue you have (I already mentioned XY Problem in your previous related post)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant not sure if i mentioned in the other post, but users of this query are unable to create tables or temp tables in GBQ,. Thus the reason why I am trying to find a solution that does not have Execute Immediate in the middle of it. Further manipulation needs to be done to the data, after it is pivoted. Thus the, before it can be used again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a temp table to store the result of dynamic sql and continue to use it later in the script.

```sql
DECLARE produces ARRAY<STRUCT<fruit STRING, trait STRING, trait_name STRING>> DEFAULT [
('Apple', 'Color', 'Red'),
('Apple', 'Texture', 'Smooth'),
('Apple', 'Size', 'Medium'),
('Banana', 'Color', 'Yellow'),
('Banana', 'Texture', 'Rough'),
('Banana', 'Size', 'Large'),
('Grape', 'Color', 'Purple'),
('Grape', 'Texture', 'Soft'),
('Grape', 'Size', 'Small')
];

CREATE TEMP TABLE Produce AS SELECT * FROM UNNEST(produces);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  CREATE TEMP TABLE pivotted_produce AS
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Produce
  ) PIVOT(ANY_VALUE(trait_name) FOR trait IN ('%s'))
""", ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT trait FROM Produce), "','"));

-- continue to use the result of pivot-ing in following script.
SELECT * FROM pivotted_produce;
```

output:

[image]